# Resource route call to wrong method

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have created route with "resource". When I try to use delete method it always going to show method.

- Route list

[image]

- Route call

  ```
  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('languages.destroy', ['language' => $language->id]) }}">Delete</a>
  ```
- Delete method

  ```
   public function destroy($language){
    $lang = Language::findOrFail($language);
    $lang->delete();


   session()->flash('flash_message', 'The language has been 
    removed!');
        return redirect(route('languages.index'));
       }
  ```

  So how to fix it?
  Thank you!

Comment: Show the code that uses that route. Are you 100% you are in fact using the DELETE request method?

Comment: @kopz Yes it is delete request.see the question, it shows use of route.

Comment: I assume you are calling that route on the frontend via some form or button. Show us that part.

Comment: You should use form method spoofing: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it goes to GET method because you are not deleting using form .

```
route('languages.destroy',['language' => $language->id])
```

the above route only generate url .so if you are using

```
<a href="{{route('languages.destroy',['language' => $language->id])}}">delete</a>
```

then it treat as get method.So you have to use

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('languages.destroy',['language' => $language->id]) }}">
    @csrf
    @method("delete")

    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('languages.destroy',$language->id) }}" method="POST"> 
      @csrf
      @method('DELETE')
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```